# Share iOS app with friends on Facebook with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

How do I share my iOS app through facebook with the facebook sdk?

Right now I get a list of all my friends I have on facebook and I show them in a tableview. I then can select them. I want to be able to share my app to the selected friends.

How do I go about this? I am using the FBSDKAppInviteDialog, and I set the content.appLinkUrl, but this requires me to still select the friends to invite. What call do I need to make that will allow me to fill the list of who I am sending the invite to?

I have been spending hours in the fbsdk docs, and haven't found the answer.

If I need to post any code or give more detail let me know.

Comment: _“but this requires me to still select the friends to invite”_ – that is on purpose. The user is supposed to select the friends they think might actually be interested in using your app; your app is not supposed to just _spam_ invites to every friend indiscriminately.

Comment: I know the app Kiwi allows you to do this. I'm trying to emulate that.

Comment: @linuxer you can try out https://www.getsocial.im/ -- it lets you invite people through Facebook or other social channels handling all the referrals, deep linking and deferred deep linking involved. (Disclosure: I'm on the team there)